# MVC 5 C# .NET Subdomain Angular

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using a  wilcard domain setup `*.domain.com`.  I am also using attribute routing on a method in my controller `Route("contact/submit")` for example.  When I hit the following method using angular `$http post` it works fine on the domain level.  As soon as I try accessing it  through any wildcard subdomain though the backend doesn't trigger and angular still hits the success method.  Does this have anything to do with cors? I have tried tinkering with that as well to no avail. If someone can please provide me some insight, I would greatly appreciate it!

setup is as follows:

TEST CONTROLLER:

```
     [HttpPost]
     [Route("test/post")]
     public void PostTest(Contact contact)
     {
       //NOT HITTING HERE WHEN ON SUBDOMAIN TEST
     }
```

ROUTING:

```
        if (request == "test") //handle subdomain route
        {
            if (path == "/")
            {
                var routeData = new RouteData(this, new MvcRouteHandler());
                routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Test");
                routeData.Values.Add("action", "Index");
                return routeData;
            }

        }
```

ANGULAR:

```
         $http({
             url: '/test/post',
             method: "POST",
             data: $scope.Contact
         }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

         }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

         });
```

Works fine locally, but when tested on subdomain (test.domain.com) it hits the success method but the backend doesn't kick in. Any suggestions?

Comment: if you have a CORS problem, you'll see it in the console of your browser when making the request. But also AngularJS http requests will not succeed when running into CORS errors, so most probably it will be some routing problem with your MVC project.

But you need to provide more information if you want help with this problem. The routing configurations, MVC Controllers as well as the AngularJS request would be the minimum.

Comment: you configure the routing to use the Index Action but your Action is PostTest? What does ´data´ in your success-callback contain?

Comment: Good suggestion, I tried data and it was hitting my error page.  Yeah I initially wanted to bring it to that view. I added else if { path = "/test/post") after the if and I get page not found in the JS console.

Comment: It seems as though routes created with attribute routing are not accessible through route data. That is my issue I believe.  I am not sure how to get around this.

Comment: I don't really understand what you intend to do with this custom routing instead of the attribute based routing.

Comment: attribute routing doesn't let me handle subdomains like *.domain.com.

Comment: Are you serving your angular application from a different subdomain from the asp application? In this case you'll be hitting CORS problems anyway, since you're not allowed (without any server configuration) to make requests to another (sub)domain.

Comment: Although I wasn't getting any Cors issue because of attribute routing it was throwing 404s. I was able to resolve the issue although I can go about it two different ways. The options depend on how I list them in RegisterRoutes.  If I put  routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); then     routes.Add(new SubdomainRoute()); it works fine and whatever pages I am able to access from my domain I can access from my subdomain.  If I swap them however I need to put in my angular to post to domain.com/test/post which works but I get a cors issue which I can easily fix.  The thing is which is the correct way?